# FTP connection creates error 500 for images

Tags: php, image, ftp, pyrocms

I've run across a strange scenario.  Whenever I connect to my shared hosting website with a ftp client, the site will experience error 500 for images and subsequently not show the images. Disconnecting the ftp client immediately fixes the issue.  So my question is, what is causing this, and how can I fix it?  Below is some information which may be relevant.  Thank you.

1and1 Hosting
PyroCMS framework
php allocated memory: 120M

Comment: Your question is not very clear... do you mean when you upload images to the webserver the FTP client experiences error 500? Or when any FTP client is connected to your webserver, whether to upload or download, your webserver's clients experience errors viewing images? Or something else altogether?

Comment: Whenever I establish a connection to the website with the ftp client (I don't have to be downloading or uploading at the time), any page views will suffer from error 500 for images.  When I disconnect the ftp client, the images on the site do not suffer from error 500.

Comment: I'm guessing some sort of resource limit - some sites only allow a limited number of processes to run at any one time and if the FTP server is running it may preclude some aspect of your web server from running.